# Why does "anonymous" need read access in authz in order for TortoiseSVN to do a diff or log?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Unless I do the following in the authz file:

```
[/some/path/to/trunk]
* = r
```

No user added for that trunk can do a diff or read the log. I don't want anyone but team members to be able to read from a directory, but unless I add anonymous read access I get an error from TortoiseSVN. Is there a way I can tell the client itself to use the auth credentials provided by a read/write user to do a diff or read the log?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently TortoiseSVN uses the read permission to determine if a diff or read on the log is possible. So if there is no read permission declared, then it can't happen. However, I think this doesn't matter, because even read only users still need to have a username/password in the user's file.

Answer (score 0):

this should be working, maybe you have some (old) user redentials still active?
Look in `%APPDATA%\\Subversion\auth\svn.simple` into each textfile and search for your URL, if there is a file with your current URL, TSVN(and svn cmd-line also!) still caches your login credentials. You can savely delete this file